# Is there an easy way to eager load all dependend objects in entity framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I use entity framework 6 to store object structures and wcf to transmit them to clients.

Lets say my class structure looks something like this:

```
+------------+
|            |
|   Class A  |
|            |
+------------+
      |1
      |
      |0.*
      v
+-----+------+
|            |
|   Class B  |
|            |
+------------+
      |1
      |
      |0.*
      v
+-----+------+
|            |
|   Class C  |
|            |
+------------+
```

Or as Code:

```
class ClassA{
    int ClassAId { get; set; }
    virtual ICollection<ClassB> ChildClasses{ get; set; }
}
class ClassB{
    int ClassBId { get; set; }
    virtual ClassA ParentClass { get; set; }
    virtual ICollection<ClassC> ChildClasses{ get; set; }
}
class ClassC{
    int ClassCId { get; set; }
    virtual ClassB ParentClass { get; set; }
    virtual ICollection<ClassB> ChildClasses{ get; set; }
}
```

Now if I want to get a `ClassA`-object and all of its dependend via a WCF service, I need to eager load all dependencies:

```
public ClassA GetClassAEntry(int entryId){
    return DbContext.ClassAEntrys.Where(entry => entry.ClassAId == entryId)
    .Include(entry => entry.ChildClasses)
    .Include(entry => entry.ChildClasses.Select(child => child.ChildClasses))
}
```

If I want to extend the service to query for `ClassB` objects and return the whole object graph:

```
public ClassB GetClassBEntry(int entryId){
    return DbContext.ClassBEntrys.Where(entry => entry.ClassBId == entryId)
    .Include(entry => entry.ChildClasses)
    .Include(entry => entry.ParentClass)
    .Include(entry => entry.ParentClass.ChildClasses)
    .Include(entry => entry.ParentClass.ChildClasses.Select(child => child.ChildClasses))
}
```

My real-world model include 9 classes, so the Includes seems to explode.

Is there an easier way to load the whole object graph then to explicitly `Include()` all dependencies?

Comment: The statement `.Include(entry => entry.ChildClasses.ChildClasses)` is not valid. If you want to drill down thru relationships to include multiple levels of related data then use `ThenInclude`

Comment: Again EF (ORM Layer) here just creating queries (based on the object relationships) in the background to finally query your database which is not always performant query. Check the SQL profiler for queries generated and validate it's performance.

Comment: @user1672994 You are right. I edited the code. But I think `ThenInclude` is only available in Ef Core?

Comment: AFAIK you can in EF6 (not core) enforce eager loading by removing the `virtual` keyword from the concrete instance. But this won't work for collection.